# SharePoint 2003 PreSaveAction() to make attachment required

Tags: javascript, 2003

I asked this question in the main SOF forum but I think it belongs here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415929/sharepoint-2003-presaveaction

I need to add a little JavaScript to run when user clicks "Save and Close". I know in SharePoint 2010 I could just use PreSaveAction() but I am using 2003.

Pseudo:

```
user clicks save and close
if attachment exists
  add the list entry
else 
  alert the user to upload attachment
```

It looks like the function ClickOnce() is what triggers the form to save since the button `href="javascript:ClickOnce()"`. So what I did was change the href of this link to my own function unless attachment exists. This did not work because it would either do nothing or fire when the page loaded whether there was an attachment or not.

Anyone have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery to change the HREF on the save button to first call your javascript and then call the ClickOnce() function.

Something like:

```
href="javascript:YourFunction();ClickOnce();"
```

Comment: This didnt work either. I think SharePoint javascript is running after mine and overwriting the href.

Comment: Use a JavaScript timeout to set your HREF 200-300 MS after the page loads.  That should give it enough time for SharePoint to do its thing, but quick enough that the user won't click the button before then.

Comment: The timeout made it work.